# Java Matcher.matches() hangs

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate string that is received with below regex (used Pattern.quote to escape characters)

```
\Q<\EProfileInfo\Q>\E(.*?)\Q<\E\Q/\EProfileInfo\Q>\E
\Q<\EProfileInfo\Q>\E(.*?)\Q<\E\Q/\EProfileInfo\Q>\E
\Q<\EProfileInfo\Q>\E(.*?)\Q<\E\Q/\EProfileInfo\Q>\E
\Q<\EProfileInfo\Q>\E(.*?)\Q<\E\Q/\EProfileInfo\Q>\E
```

Application is getting hung if I use this regex

I am seeing below exception in thread dump

```
"pinnedDispatcher-pinnedDispatcher-22" #82 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000020be1000 nid=0x2500 runnable [0x0000000029f59000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4717)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4287)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4236)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)
```

Any idea how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to capture the content of 4 consecutive `<EProfileInfo>` elements? Why not use an XML parser?

Comment: Post minimal code that reproduces this error. If you can't then describe how your program is structured leading up to the use of the regex

Comment: `<` and `>` are not regex special characters so they shouldn't require escaping (with `\Q...\E` section). Similarly `/` (at least in Java - not to be confused with JavaScript).

Comment: Yes correct, I cannot use XML parser. The input I receive may be in XML/JSON etc.may be any format.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to escape `<`, `>`, or `/` in a Java regex. Second, if you want the same pattern 4 times, use `{4}` instead of repeating the pattern. So, your regex can be simplified to:

```
(?:<ProfileInfo>.*?</ProfileInfo>){4}
```

Of course, if you actually need to *capture* the 4 contents, you have to repeat pattern 4 times, but since you're just validating, and didn't show any use of the captures, I'll assume you didn't actually need to capture the contents.

Now, the performance issue is one of near-infinite backtracking. If the content only has 3 `<ProfileInfo>` elements, it backtracks a lot before it would eventually fail.

Your regex technically allows the content of a `<ProfileInfo>` to contain the `</ProfileInfo>` text. If the subsequent matching fails, the `.*?` will begin match the `</ProfileInfo>` text to see if the subsequent matching will work if it does.

That's the backtracking taking forever, and is entirely useless in your case.

To prevent that, use a [possessive](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) match to prevent backtracking, and a negative look-ahead to prevent it from matching the end tag.

```
(?:<ProfileInfo>((?:(?!</ProfileInfo>).)*+)</ProfileInfo>){4}
```

It can be optimized more by only doing the negative look-ahead when a `<` is encountered *(splitting and indenting for readability)*:

```
(?:
  <ProfileInfo>                   match start tag
  (?:
    [^<]*+                          skip until '<' (fast)
    (?:                             match '<'
      <
      (?!/ProfileInfo>)               but not if beginning of end tag
    )?+
  )*+                             repeat if '<' was matched
  </ProfileInfo>                  match end tag
){4}                            repeat 4 times
```

The repeating patterns are [possessive](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) (`+`), i.e. they will not backtrack to try alternative regex path if a matching failure occurs.

Comment: Thanks for solution. But this regex is given by user , I cannot convert input dynamically to use possessive match. I need to use input given by user as is and capture the groups

Comment: @Nagendra If user is writing the regex, and writing a bad one, then user gets to live with the bad performance of the regex they wrote.

Comment: unfortunately that is the requirement. Also, Pattern.compile is also not throwing any exception and considered as valid, is there any alternative way where I can replace (.*?) with different regex and capture the group?